# php how to pass an anchor in the command line

Tags: php, html, parameters, anchor

I need to pass parameters and an anchor in a php program to make sure the cursor is positioned at the last place it was in the page when it returns.

```
program.php?ID=123&ID2=456#777
```

ID=123

ID2=456

html anchor is #777

Can someone tell me how to make this work? Since it isn't working the way I'm doing it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not send the anchor to web server.

So PHP can't get the anchor from url.

maybe you can use javascript to request `program.php?ID=123&ID2=456&anchor=777`, then you can get the anchor by `$_GET['anchor']`.

Sorry for my bad english (ㄒoㄒ).

---

If you want force the cursor to the position.

this code will redirect to `http://website.com/page.php#anchor` and the broswer will auto cursor the position.

```
<?php
header("location: http://website.com/page.php#anchor");
exit;
```

**warning: take care about `header` function, there is the manual [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-description)**

**If the current page is the same as the redirect page, above the code will infinite redirect and the browser will throw error. So you have to write some logic, make it redirect when you want. Or just write two different page, one to show content, other one redirect to content page with anchor.**

But I still think it is better to do that by JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So if I just pass the anchor as a parameter &ANCHOR=777 and then get it with $_GET['ANCHOR'], how can I force the cursor to the position I want with php?

Comment: Thanks but you miss understood, I need to pass arguments AND an anchor. So something like header("location: http://website.com/page.php?ARG=1#anchor"); And the program is not calling itself. Prog1 calls Prog2 and then Prog2 calls Prog1. So when Prog2 calls Prog1 it needs to pass the arguments AND the anchor so that when Prog1 displays the page it puts the cursor at the location where it called Prog2 from the last time.